# how can i let a div show when i click it using Angular2

Tags: angular

following is my temporary solotion to show/hide an ul-list, but i want to accomplish it with Angular 2.

//Here is the **app.component.ts**

```
@component({
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    UserLists: UserList[];
    showhide(id: string){
        var e=document.getElementById(id);
        e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}
```

//Here is the **user.service.ts**

```
export class UserList{
    name: string;
    link: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
    UserLists: UserList[] = AdminList;
}
export var AdminList: UserList[]=[{
    name: "a",
    link: ""
    },{
    name: "b",
    link: ""
}]
```

Here is the **app.component.html**

```
<div class="user">welcome<a class="user-name" (click)="showhide('user-list')"><span>admin<img src="a.png"></span></a>
    <div id="user-list" class="user-list" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let list of UserLists">
                <a [routerLink]="[list.link]" routerLinkActive="active">{{list.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple - just add a member variable to your `AppComponent`:

```ts
@component({
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    UserLists: UserList[];
    showUserList: boolean = true; // <-- member variable to hold status
}
```

And in your HTML template you toggle it on click and leverage `*ngIf` to show/hide it:

```html
<div class="user">welcome<a class="user-name" (click)="showUserList = !showUserList"><span>admin<img src="a.png"></span></a>
    <div id="user-list" class="user-list" *ngIf="showUserList">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let list of UserLists">
                <a [routerLink]="[list.link]" routerLinkActive="active">{{list.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIf or [hidden] in your user list div. y or may not need the showhide method. Like this:-

In your html

```
<div class="user">welcome<a class="user-name" (click)="showList = !showList"><span>admin<img src="a.png"></span></a>
<div id="user-list" class="user-list" *ngIf="showList">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let list of UserLists">
            <a [routerLink]="[list.link]" routerLinkActive="active">{{list.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```